# missing library "jansson_private_config.h" in Jansson c parser library

Tags: c

Anyone ever used jansson C-parser for parsing JSON objects. I was trying to study the library, for same I compiled it with the sample program given with it. Added the header files required but one header file is missing named "jansson_private_config.h" I have downloaded this library completely I am not sure where I can get this ??

Comment: Shouldn't this file be created by some `./configure` script?

Comment: okay, I missed it probably. thanks @Mathieu

Comment: "there’s no ./configure script as it’s not kept in version control. To create the script, the build system needs to be bootstrapped. There are many ways to do this, but the easiest one is to use autoreconf:

autoreconf -fi"
this is what jansson site says, want to build this library on windows , is this possible and how can I achieve that ??

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: windows 10 Enterprise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find in [documentation](https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted.html#windows-visual-studio) how to build this library for windows:

- Get CMake and Visual Studio
- unpack source

In a command line

- `cd .../jansson-2.12`
- `mkdir build`
- `cd build`
- `cmake -G "Visual Studio XX 20XX" ..`

You should be done

---

[Alternate method](https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted.html#other-systems)

You can also edit manually the `jansson_config.h.in`, ommitting to define `HAVE_CONFIG_H` which cause the `jansson_private_config.h` to be included in .c files.

Note that this `#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H` test has been forgetten in `test_dump.c`, which won't compile if you don't fix it.

Fix proposal (not tested):

```
+#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
 #include "jansson_private_config.h"
+#endif
```